# Relative and absolute positioning inside inline-block

Tags: html, css

I want to place news post in (x) number of columns, depending from the window size. I'm stuck with something what seems to be easy but i can't fix it. I want to float the .box-category element over the image. To achieve this i wanted to set the .box-image position to relative, and the box-category to absolute. When i set the .box-image position to relative, the images are disappearing from the second and third column. When i only set the .box-category to absolute, it showy up only in the first column. What i'm doing wrong and how can i fix it?

**There are some screenshots about the results:**

Only box-category position:absolute;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B66mAnIw9SMqMmlvSlNEZ2NYLVE/view
(category names are in the same column)

boc-category: absolute, box-image: relative;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B66mAnIw9SMqa3dBZWpuOFpBekU/view
(category names are in the right place but without text, images doesn't rendering in the 2nd and 3rd boxes)

**The code:**

```
{extends file="Global/index.tpl"}
{block name=index}
<style>
//COLUMN COUNT  HANDLING
.contentColumns { /* Masonry container */
    -moz-column-count: 3 !important;
    -webkit-column-count: 3 !important;
    column-count: 3 !important;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 992px){
    .contentColumns {
        -moz-column-count: 2 !important;
        -webkit-column-count: 2 !important;
        column-count: 2 !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px){
    .contentColumns {
        -moz-column-count: 1 !important;
        -webkit-column-count: 1 !important;
        column-count: 1 !important;
    }
}

//ITEMS TO PLACE INSIDE COLUMNS

.box {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.12);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.12);
    box-shadow:         0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.12);
    padding-bottom: 15px;
 }

.box-more {

   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   padding-left: 7px;
   padding-right: 7px;

   border-radius: 3px;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;

}

.box-category {

   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   padding-left: 7px;
   padding-right: 7px;
   text-transform: uppercase;

}

.box-content {
    text-align: justify;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.box-footer {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: #BBB;
}

.box-title {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    height: 40px !important; 
}
.box-title h4 {
    line-height: 40px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.box-image{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="contentColumns">
        {foreach $items as $news_item}
            <div class="box">  

                <div class="box-image">
                    <span style="position: absolute;" class="box-category">category name</span>
                    <img style="width: 100%;" src="{$base}{$news_item.news_image}">
                </div>

                <div class="box-title">
                    <h4>{$news_item.news_title}</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="box-content">
                    <p>{$news_item.news_quote}</p>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="box-footer">

                    <span class="pull-left">
                         {$news_item.date_posted|date_format}
                    </span>

                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <a href="" style="color: #00a8ff; border: 1px solid #ddd;" class="box-more">Read More</a>
                    </span>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                </div>

            </div>
        {foreachelse}
            There are no news posts.
        {/foreach}
    </div>
</div>

{/block}
```